# How to solve problems such as $x = \log_2{x}$

Tags: logarithms

How does one go about solving $x = \log_2{x}$? Is there a technique to solve these sorts of problems?

Comment: Use the method of Newton - Raphson to find a root of the equation $x-\log_2x=0$. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method

Answer (score 4):

There are no elementary formulas for such equations. Using the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), the solution is $x = e^{-W(-\log2)}$.

Answer (score 2):

This can be "solved" using the Lambert W function. The [example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Example_1) on the wikipedia page is fundamentally the same as your question, after rewriting as $2^x=x$.

Answer (score 1):

There are. Look at it as an intersection of two functions - $$f(x)=x$$ and $$g(x)=\log_2(x)=\ln(x)/\ln(2)$$ both functions are monotone increasing. Find their derivatives, and check if they can ever meet, and how many times. Separate the search to $(0,1)$ and $(1,\infty)$.